# How does underscore replace variables?

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, frontend

I have following row in code:

```
 terminalsListHtml += this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

Behaviour of execution this row is surprising for me.

I evaluate argument value of `this.compiled` method.
It looks like this:

[image]

more details:

```
compiled: _.template($('#terminal-template').text())
```

[image]
Lets return to first row whos result is surprising for me:

it returns following result:

```
this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
"
    <li data-terminal-id="201" class="">
        <label>
             
          <input type="checkbox" name="terminal" class="all" data-terminal-id="201" />
            <a href="#" title="" class="image"><img
                    src="getMediumThumbnail/1"
                    alt=""/></a>   
            <h3>Second
                <small>Lenina, 5</small>
            </h3>
            <p>Second</p>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>10</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>5</span> руб./час</p>

            <p class="count">Количество свободных слотов: <span>10</span> </p>
        </label>
    </li>
"
```

As we can see `{{imageId}}` was replaced with `1`.

I don't understand where does this `1` takes.
Please clarify.

### P.P.S.

Sorry for screenshots instead of copied code. I wanted to pasted code but it render bad.

Comment: please read comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28180350/2674303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
 compiled: _.template($('#terminal-template').text())
```

turns a string (the text contents of an element with `id="terminal-template"`) into a function that can be evaluated later: http://underscorejs.org/#template

then calling `this.compiled( object )` renders the template (calls te previously compiled template function) with the `object` set as the context, so if the object has a key `imageId` it will be substituted in place of `{{imageId}}` in the template string. It looks like the object returned from `_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj)` has that key and it is equal to `1`.

Judging by the screenshot you have provided maybe it should produce `<img src="getMediumThumbnail/undefined" ... />`.
But the `imageId` may come from the object's prototype or even from the global scope (which has been confirmed in the discussion in comments: `window.imageId == 1`).

EDIT: what is strange is that underscore only reaches the global scope when `_.templateSettings` is used to change the syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/hoy9ga0d/ - using default `<%= variable %>` doesn't render a global variable, but `{{ variable }}` does.

Comment: @gstackoverflow could you try `_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj).imageId` and `window.imageId` and check if any of them returns `1`?

Comment: window.imageId returns 1

Comment: @gstackoverflow So it comes from global scope as I have suspected. It looks like scoping issue, IMO it shouldn't go outside of the scope of `object` passed to `compiled()` (there could be some checks in the library), but it's kind of the way JS was designed.

Comment: Could you provide fix?

Comment: @gstackoverflow unfortunately I'm in no position to patch the library and I can understand why the check isnt' there - it would need to call `if( context.hasOwnProperty( key ) )` in every substitution of `{{ key }}` which would be a drawback performance-wise. Now it just resolves to the value of `key` according to the rules of resolving variables in the JS language. You could `delete window.imageId` if and when you know you won't gonna need it.

Comment: @gstackoverflow see my recent edit. maybe you can work from there, or file a bug report.

Comment: interesting behaviour)